# How to restart IIS on all servers of farm from SharePoint Application Page

Tags: asp.net, iis, restart

SharePoint provides an option in Create New WebApplication page that says Restart IIS Automatically. This restarts IIS on all servers of the farm.

What can I do to trigger this programmatically from my Application Page (ASP.NET)?

Is there a timer job for this?
Is there anything in the API?
do I have to create "iisreset" process and pass it the name of servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new web application a timer job is created to run seperatly on ALL servers, this timer job will perform the IISReset - It uses remoting to call into IIS - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcclientchannel.aspx - however I find these kind of tasks easier using WMI.

If you wanted to replicate this exact functionality then a timer job that is set to run on all servers independantly will be sufficient, my first port of call would be to take a look at the SPWebApplicationProvisioningJobDefinition using Reflector, this will show you exactly how they do it :)

Stuart